# How can i get a wordpress plugin to enable visitors from frontend to sort posts by ascending order or descending order

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, wordpress

Any help will be much appreciated. I would prefer a wordpress plugin. But if there is none, I don't mind having a php code to help me. Bear in mind please, I am no php expert.

I saw this on the wordpress codex but do not know how to use it:

```
    function wp_list_sort( $list, $orderby = array(), $order = 'ASC', $preserve_keys = false ) {
    if ( ! is_array( $list ) ) {
        return array();
    }
 
    $util = new WP_List_Util( $list );
    return $util->sort( $orderby, $order, $preserve_keys );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-types-order/) to sorting your Posts and Post Types

It's a powerful plugin, Order Posts and Post Types Objects using a Drag and Drop Sortable JavaScript capability.

Comment: thanks. but just to be sure, does it do it from the frontend?

Comment: Please read the latest response. I have added a few sample codes, it may help you.

Comment: Another link you can visit :

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12916/is-there-any-way-of-changing-the-post-order-via-user-click

it may help you :).

Answer (score 0):

basically, you can order from your dashboard by this plugin but you can make it for the frontend as well but you need to do a few custom codes.

Here is another solution you may try it on your frontend code :

```
<div class="order-posts">
<div class="order-posts-container">
<?php
    global $wp;
    $current_url = home_url( $wp->request ) . '/'; // last part adds the "/" at the end
?>
<form name="George">
<select class="select-form" name="example" size="1" onChange="go()">
<option selected disabled class="select-form-item 0" value>-- Change order --</option>
<option class="select-form-item 1" value="<?php echo $current_url ?>">Order by default</option>
<option class="select-form-item 2" value="<?php echo $current_url ?>?orderby=title&order=asc">Order from A to Z</option>
<option class="select-form-item 3" value="<?php echo $current_url ?>?orderby=title&order=desc">Order from Z to A</option>
<option class="select-form-item 4" value="<?php echo $current_url ?>?orderby=date&order=desc">Order from new to old</option>
<option class="select-form-item 5" value="<?php echo $current_url ?>?orderby=date&order=asc">Order from old to new</option>
<option class="select-form-item 6" value="<?php echo $current_url ?>?orderby=comment_count&order=desc">Order by comment count 0 - 999</option>
<option class="select-form-item 7" value="<?php echo $current_url ?>?orderby=comment_count&order=asc">Order by comment count 999 - 0</option>
<option class="select-form-item 8" value="<?php echo $current_url ?>?orderby=rand&posts_per_page=10">Random order</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">

function go(){
location=
document.George.example.
options[document.George.example.selectedIndex].value
}
 
</script>
<input type="button" class="button-form" name="sort-posts-button" value="Go!" onClick="go()">
</form>
</div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. am i adding this code snippet to the functions.php in my site?

Comment: about the few custom codes to enable the wordpress plugin you mentioned work on the frontend , could you help with that?